# I want to achieve different workflow for same issue type in Jira

Tags: jira

In my project i have 2 kinds of task, one is normal task which has different workflow and the other task is performance testing task. I am trying to introduce this new performance testing task and also workflow needs to be different for this task. So what should be type of this new task so that it has different workflow. How can this be achieved.

Comment: So basically you trying to create new workflow?

Comment: This should be what you're looking for: https://community.atlassian.com/t5/JIRA-questions/How-can-I-add-different-workflows-per-issue-type-in-Jira/qaq-p/297865 Look for 'workflow schemes'

Comment: Check creating a workflow here or as @Our_Benefactors suggested best thing to ask in above link 

https://confluence.atlassian.com/adminjiraserver072/working-with-workflows-828787890.html

Comment: Yes create new workflow but i dont want to change the already created workflow for type "task". So i want something like checkbox which i can use while creating a new task to tell that this is task of type performance and so the newly created workflow will be applied on this. Also i dont want to do this by creating a new type, but i want to do this using existing type "task"

Comment: @shivamgoel, did you try what was suggested in the link I posted? It describes your usecase exactly.

Comment: @Our_Benefactors Yes i read it. It is for creating workflow for different issue types. but i want different workflow for same issue type

Comment: In that case, no, you cannot create a subclass of a task type. You will need to individually define the different task types.